# Выровнять изображения по центру

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть следующая структура:

```
<p>
    <img src = "..."></img>
    Текст...
</p>
```

Тег `img` может иметь `float: left`. Как можно выровнять изображения во всем подобном документе по центру при условии, что у них отсутствует `float: left`?

Answer (score 1):

Задать ширину и задать

```
margin: 0 auto; float: none; display: block
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85kc94eo/1/